# constraintlayout - set a view padding depending on another view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to know if I can set the title of TextView_1 to be centered of the parent view but ellipsize end against TextView_2 like picture below by using constraint layout. if the text in TextView_1 gets longer then, make it ellipsized. and below would be the case where I wanted to put "Text to be centered but ellipsize against TextView_2 when it gets longer".

what I have tried are

1. I programmatically tried to get the width of TextView_2 and set it to padding right of TextView_1. but failed since I wasn't able to get the width of TextView_2(I get 0) since it is set to be 0dp in constraint layout to be stretched.
2. I tried to find a way to set TextView_1 padding as TextView_2 size in xml file but that doesn't seem to be possible.

I have no more good idea to make it work. is there any work around for it? I will appreciate your help in advance.

[image: centered_title_but_padding_against_other_textView]

Comment: Could you maybe add the xml code of you layout to your question? That would help to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post code, but I don't think you waited for the layout to occur to get the size of *textView2*. Here is some working code with the following XML. The code runs in the `onCreateView()` function of the *Fragment*. After layout, the width of *TextView2* is set to the start/left padding of *TextView1*.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Text to be centered but ellipsize against TextView_2 when it gets longer"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(requireActivity(), R.layout.fragment_main)
binding.root.doOnNextLayout {
    binding.textView1.updatePadding(binding.textView2.width)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to change a bit though but It works as I almost expected. Thank you.